# Refreshing tokens in Cognito constantly fails with "invalid_grant" / "Invalid Refresh Token" error

Tags: oauth, amazon-cognito, amazon-cognito-identity-js

I keep on getting an "invalid grant" error, yet for what I can tell I am doing it all as per spec. I can get the tokens just fine:

```
aws cognito-idp initiate-auth --auth-flow USER_PASSWORD_AUTH --auth-parameters USERNAME=admin,PASSWORD=adminadmin,SECRET_HASH=Ol... --client-id 2pg...
```

That command gets me this:

[image: Tokens Generated by AWS CLI]

Yet when I actually try to use the refresh token, I keep on getting:

```
An error occurred (NotAuthorizedException) when calling the InitiateAuth operation: Invalid Refresh Token.
```

[image: Invalid Refresh Token]

App client seem to be configured properly. I don't have device tracking setup and the app config seems to allow refresh tokens too:

[image: Cognito App Config - Refrehs]

Similar error when invoking oauth2/token endpoint via Insomina:

[image: Insomnia Error]

Where did I go wrong? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: having the same with "Invalid Refresh Token", which used to work ok..  checked the devices (which showed only on the old interface) but didn't help.

Answer (score 1):

Turned out this behaviour was due to the device tracking being turned on. Not sure it's a bug or a feature, but after turning it off refresh tokens started to work like charm:

[image: Device Tracking in Cognito]